# How to compute means μ1 and μ2 knowing sum of Skellam distributions f(k;μ1,μ2) and sum μ1+μ2, where k is from 2 to n?

Tags: probability-distributions, bessel-functions

The probability mass function for the [Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution) for a count difference $  k=n_1-n_2 $ from two [Poisson-distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) variables with means $\mu_1$ and $\mu_1$ is given by:

$$ f(k;\mu_1,\mu_2)= e^{-(\mu_1+\mu_2)}
  \left({\mu_1\over\mu_2}\right)^{k/2}I_{|k|}(2\sqrt{\mu_1\mu_2}) $$
where $I_k(z)$ is the modified [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) of the first kind.

I know the sum of these functions for k from 2 to n 
$$ \sum_{k=2}^n f(k;\mu_1,\mu_2) = a$$

I also know the sum $\mu_1 + \mu_2 = \mu$. So i can substitute $\mu_1$ for $\mu - \mu_2. $
So i have $$ a = \sum_{k=2}^n e^{-(\mu_1+\mu_2)}
  \left({\mu_1\over\mu_2}\right)^{k/2}I_{|k|}(2\sqrt{\mu_1\mu_2}) = \sum_{k=2}^n e^{-(\mu)}
  \left({\mu - \mu_2\over\mu_2}\right)^{k/2}I_{|k|}(2\sqrt{(\mu - \mu_2)\mu_2})$$

My question is how can i compute $\mu_2$ from this equation if it's possible.

Comment: Why $|k|$ in $I_{|k|}(2\sqrt{\mu1\mu2})$ if you sum up for $k$ from 2 to $n$?

Comment: @user64494 yes, you are right. I just wrote a common formula, as this does not matter for this case.

Comment: I think it can be done numerically by CASes in the case of concrete $n, \mu$ and $a$ only.

Comment: @user64494 yes, we know these concrete parameters. Can we compute, for example, if n = 5, μ = 3.18 and a = 0.22?  This decision for concrete numbers will be valued for me. What CASes are u talking about?

Comment: Rather than paying, you can try using WolframAlpha Open Code, which has Bessel function support: https://www.open.wolframcloud.com/env/b5b25415-524b-4d76-8af6-30c0340f7a88#sidebar=compute

Answer (score 1):

Here is its numerical solution for required values of parameters done with Maple:

```
a := .22: n := 5: mu := 3.18:
 fsolve(a = add(exp(-mu)*((mu-mu2)/mu2)^(k/2)*BesselI(k, 2*sqrt((mu-mu2)*mu2)), k = 1 .. n));
```

$2.002275629 $

Comment: Can you provide it with any formulas? I need common solution, where i will compute with certain parameters. As i understand in this case, for other parameters i should buy this maple software?